# Get Paypal API Credentials from SDK

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have different questions about Paypal API Credentials

- Is it possible to retrieve User API credentials (Classic API Signature) for a paypal business account from code?, maybe calling a method of the PayPal SDK to access his profile?. I want to code something that checks if Merchant does not have API credentials, in case that he has them, store them in my local database for payment operations and if not, maybe redirect him to a video explaining how to do this.
- Are those credentials different for each merchant account?
- Is there a way to have the same credentials for different users using classic API?. I know Rest API Allows to do this (with client id and secret), but it does not allow me to do embedded payments, so that's why I'm using the classic API.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. The API doesn't have anything like that. Either you need to post API calls using their API credentials or have them authorize your API username to run calls on their behald (where you pass their primary email address in the API calls).

Comment: Do you know a link where I can see the second option that you mentioned? Thanks a lot @Machavity

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/permissions-service/ht_permissions-invoice/